# Copy rows based on cell value and paste on a new sheet with same cell value name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a DATA sheet containing an employee list with 3 columns,

```
COLUMN A - DEPARTMENT
COLUMN B - EMPCODE
COLUMN C - EMPNAME
```

Here is sample data:

[image: Raw data]

I want to split the contents of this sheet according to COLUMN A - DEPARMENT and place them on different sheets, the new sheets to be named as the department name in Column A.

The end result should be something like this:

[image: End result]

This code checks each row. If the cell in Column A is equal to the cell below, it selects the row.

```
Sub CopyRows()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range
    With Worksheets("DATA")
     Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("a1"), .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

     For Each rngCell In rngMyRange
            If rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            rngCell.EntireRow.Select
         End If

     Next
         Selection.Copy
         Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
         Rows("1:1").Select
         Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
         ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A1")
 End With

 End Sub
```

How can I make the selection stay and add more selected rows as it checks the cell value in Column A?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [RemoveDuplicates()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823(v=office.15)) and [Autofilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) methods of Range object as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim depSheet As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("DATA") '<--|refer to data sheet
        .Rows(1).Insert '<--|insert a temporary header row: it'll be used for AutoFilter() method and eventually deleted
        .Cells(1, 1).value = "Department" '<--| place a dummy header in the temporary header row
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count) '<--| refer to a "helper" column out of the used range and limited to column "A" last non empty row
            .value = .Offset(, -.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).value '<--| duplicate departments (column "A") values in helper one
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), header:=xlYes '<--| leave only departments unique values in "helper" column
            For Each rngCell In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--|loop through "helper" column departments unique values
                Set depSheet = GetSheet(.Parent.Parent, rngCell.value) '<--|get or add the worksheet corresponding to current department
                With .Offset(, -.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1) '<--|refer to departments column
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=rngCell.value '<--| filter it on current department value
                    With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| refer to department filtered cells
                        depSheet.Cells(depSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Cells.Count, 3).value = .Resize(, 3).value '<--|copy their values along with columns "B" and "C" ones into first empty row of the corresponding worksheet
                    End With
                End With
            Next rngCell
            .ClearContents '<--| clear "helper" column
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows(1).Delete '<--| delete temporary header row
    End With
 End Sub

Function GetSheet(wb As Workbook, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = wb.Worksheets(shtName) '<--| try and set a sheet with passed name
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then '<--| if there weas no such sheet...
        Set GetSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet) '<--|... add a new sheet
        With GetSheet
            .Name = shtName '<--|rename it after passed name
            .Range("A1:C1").value = Array("DEPARTMENT", "EMPCODE", "EMPNAME") '<--| add headers
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Eileen: did you get through it?

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Too bad @Eileen doesn't seem to be interested in this question anymore. I modifies the `GetSheet` function to bypass the max length limit for a sheet name in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I've created this VBA to copy data from one sheet (source) to another sheet (target) based on conditional data given in 3rd sheet (condition):

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Condition As Worksheet


    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("source")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("target")
    Set Condition = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("condition")

    j = 1    'This will start copying data to Target sheet at row 1
      For Each d In Condition.Range("A1:A86")
        For Each c In Source.Range("B2:B1893")
            If d = c Then
                Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next c
      Next d
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put together a pretty good question. It has a clear description of the starting point and what the objective is. The code you have is a good start towards the answer. However I didn't try to group a bunch of rows together like you wanted to do because I had no idea of how to do that. What I did was to loop through the DATA range and then deal with each row one at a time. If the destination worksheet existed, I inserted the row after the last row. If the destination sheet did not exist, I created the new sheet the way you were doing. Step through this with the debugger and you'll be able to see how it works.

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SheetName As String



With Worksheets("DATA")
Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("a1"), .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

    For Each rngCell In rngMyRange

        rngCell.EntireRow.Select

        Selection.Copy

        If (WorksheetExists(rngCell.Value)) Then
            SheetName = rngCell.Value
            Sheets(SheetName).Select
            Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
            LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            Rows(LastRow + 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Else
            Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
            Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            ActiveSheet.Name = rngCell.Value
        End If


        'Go back to the DATA sheet
        Sheets("DATA").Select
    Next

End With

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies. I actually found a pretty good code that does exactly what I wanted, I forgot to note down the reference site though. Here's the code if anyone's interested:

```
    Sub parse_data()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    vcol = 1
    Set ws = Sheets("DATA")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:J1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
    Next
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    End Sub
```

Comment: it's a bad code with that `On error Resume Next`. Did you try mine?

Answer (score 0):

But Eileen,
If we need to copy cell values of COLUMN E, rather than COLUMN A and paste on new sheet, then your ref code still lists values from COLUMN A......! 
So we need just to change vcol = 5 on line 9

Answer (score 0):

I modified [user3598756's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803096/1445318) above to bypass restrictions on the max length allowed for the name of a sheet. It will concatenate the first and last 13 characters of the name with 4 dots in between

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim depSheet As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Worksheets("DATA") '<--|refer to data sheet
        .Rows(1).Insert '<--|insert a temporary header row: it'll be used for AutoFilter() method and eventually deleted
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Table_Name" '<--| place a dummy header in the temporary header row
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.count) '<--| refer to a "helper" column out of the used range and limited to column "A" last non empty row
            .Value = .Offset(, -.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.count).Value '<--| duplicate departments (column "A") values in helper one
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes '<--| leave only departments unique values in "helper" column
            For Each rngCell In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--|loop through "helper" column departments unique values
                Set depSheet = GetSheet(.Parent.Parent, rngCell.Value) '<--|get or add the worksheet corresponding to current department
                With .Offset(, -.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.count + 1) '<--|refer to departments column
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=rngCell.Value '<--| filter it on current department value
                    With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| refer to department filtered cells
                        depSheet.Cells(depSheet.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Cells.count, 3).Value = .Resize(, 3).Value '<--|copy their values along with columns "B" and "C" ones into first empty row of the corresponding worksheet
                    End With
                End With
            Next rngCell
            .ClearContents '<--| clear "helper" column
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows(1).Delete '<--| delete temporary header row
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Sub

Function GetSheet(wb As Workbook, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = wb.Worksheets(shtName) '<--| try and set a sheet with passed name
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then '<--| if there weas no such sheet...
        Dim count As Long
        count = Len(shtName)
        Dim newName As String
        If count > 30 Then
            newName = Left(shtName, 13) & "...." & Right(shtName, 13)
        Else
            newName = shtName
        End If
        Set GetSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet) '<--|... add a new sheet
        With GetSheet
            .Name = newName '<--|rename it after passed name
            .Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("DEPARTMENT", "EMPCODE", "EMPNAME") '<--| add headers
        End With
    End If
End Function
```